# bootstrap 2 column layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: bootstrap 2 column layout]

Hello everyone,

I am looking for some assistance here.
I have been requested to make the design above and am having issues with it as I am unable to create the 2 columns correctly.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="blogHead">
            <h2>The Cycle to Work Scheme information</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="blogBody">
            <p>Some text.</p><a class="btn lightBlueSolid">Press For More Information</a>
        </div>
    </div><!---- I repeat this div a few times -->
    <div class="col-md-5"><img alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pad-20" src="images/insentives/bike.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Could I please get some guidance here, please do not post code. I seek guidance, not a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a table with 12 columns. That's the logic Bootstrap uses.

So you have to decide what proportion you want. I'd say you want 8/12 columns for the left and side of your content, which leaves 4/12 columns for the right (in other words, the main chunk of your content takes up the first 75% of the page horizontally).

The code you need would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- All the stuff here to link to Bootstrap -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- SIDEBAR CONTENT HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In each div you can then use div id="row" to have content aligned horizontally between the two if you need that.

Hopefully that helps. It might be worth reviewing the Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as an answer and/or upvote it :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very basic and you will find all you need on the official [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) with lots of examples.

Comment: Your answer is very basic and could have been made into a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Sure but I need a reputation of 50 in order to comment the initial question. ;)

Comment: It's generally off-topic and frowned upon to post an answer that should be a comment, regardless of your reputation. Please look at [what you should do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class=col-md-9 pull-left>
your left side content
</div>
<div class =col-md-3>
right side form
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you used pull wrong for columns: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering. Second of all, there's really no need for it with the simple layout he's going for. Third, I don't see the point in putting the md 9 and 3 divs inside of an md 12 div.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-7"> 
            <!--This one here is the left part of the page, and it contains 
            as many rows as you want, rows defines your Blocks -->

                <div class="row">

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
            <!-- here is the Right part of your page, costumize it as you 
            wish -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```